# UITableViewCell Added UISwitch on change show UIbutton on cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I want to Show/Hide `UIButton` as per the state of `UISwitch` on/off. While scrolling tableview `UIButton` gets change state.. It display on other cell also. Please advise.
In `UITableViewCell`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    EnhancedChecklistTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if ( cell == nil )
    {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects;
        if(IS_IPAD)
        {
            topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"EnhancedChecklistTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];

        }
        else
        {
            topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"EnhancedChecklistTableViewCell_Iphone" owner:self options:nil];

        }
        for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects){
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[EnhancedChecklistTableViewCell class]])
            {
                cell = (EnhancedChecklistTableViewCell *)currentObject;
                cell.delegate = self;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    R5OPERATORACTCHECKLISTS *inspectionTasks = [_data objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    return cell;
}
```

all the Switches are added using xib file in custom cell. I have used one method which will fire after value change event. and as per the state of the switch I am displaying button. But while scrolling it disturb.

Comment: can you share some code what you have tried so that we can help.

Comment: Cells are reused; You can't rely on the state of a switch in the cell itself; you need to store the switch state in some data structure, such as an array, and use this in `cellForRowAt:` to reset the cell state

Comment: Please show your code. @Swati

Comment: I have used custom cell. and added switch from xib file. on value change event of the switch like  if (sender == _buttonFollowUp ) {
        self.followUp = !_followUp;
      self.btnSave.hidden = NO;
    }  else if (sender == _buttonFinalOccurence ) {
        self.finalOccurence = !_finalOccurence;
   
self.btnSave.hidden = NO;
    } added like this .. but after scrolling tableview .. save button will appear on all the cells.

Comment: Can you show me your `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
` func ? I will help you. :)

Comment: In the code you have shown, you need to check some array or variable where you have stored the required state for the button in that cell and either hide it or show it.

Answer (score 0):

create .h file `bool`variable name "switchFlag" and default set `YES`and after that you can check in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                      reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    }
    if (switchFlag ==YES)
    {
        NSLog(@"Switch On");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Switch Off");
    }
}
```

and when you click on `UISwitch` that time change Value **switchFlag** set `YES` Or `NO` depends on UISwitch State, so it's giving you expected output , i hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this

First you can take NSMutableArray with switches default state is On/Off (1/0).

```
self.switchStateArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"1",@"1",@"1",@"1",@"1",@"1",@"1", nil];
```

And in cellForRowAtIndexPath you can call the below method on switch action

```
cell.normalSwitch.tag = indexPath.row;

[cell.normalSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchToggle:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

 cell.normalSwitch.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

if (cell.normalSwitch.isOn)
{
    cell.buttonName.hidden = NO;

    NSLog(@"Switch is On");
}
else
{
    cell.buttonName.hidden = YES;

   NSLog(@"Switch is Off");

}
```

//Switch Action

```
-(void)switchToggle:(id)sender
{
    UISwitch *theSwitch = (UISwitch *)sender;

    NSLog(@"tag %ld",(long)theSwitch.tag);
    NSInteger index = [sender tag];

    if (theSwitch.isOn)
    {
        [self.switchStateArray replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:@"1"];
        [theSwitch setOn:YES animated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.switchStateArray replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:@"0"];
        [theSwitch setOn:NO animated:YES];
    }

    [self.tableviewName reloadData];


}
```